# Change bibliography name to Supplementary References

Tags: natbib, revtex

I would like to call the references section Supplementary References.

Currently, there is a line above the references with no section name.

If I use the `\def\bibsection{\section*{Supplementary References}}`
 as suggested in other threads this will display as Supplementary References and a section number at the end. I suppose this is because of this line `\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}{#1\ \thesection}`.

How could I do this without displaying the number, just Supplementary References?

```
\documentclass[11pt,prb,superscriptaddress,notitlepage,amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm]{revtex4-1}
\def\bibsection{\section*{\refname}} 

%\def\bibsection{\section*{Supplementary References}} 
%\renewcommand\refname{Reference}

% encoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}{#1\ \thesection}

%graphics
\usepackage{graphicx}
\linespread{1.5}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.1cm plus4mm minus3mm}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=0.75in, right=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%figures
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{figure}
\usepackage{placeins}

% Math packages
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\usepackage[hyperindex,colorlinks,hyperfootnotes = false,citecolor = blue,]{hyperref}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\maketitle

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Supplementary Figure}
\renewcommand\theequation{S\arabic{equation}}

\section{Supplementary Note}

\begin{thebibliography}{10}

\bibitem{becker}
N.~B. Becker, A.~Mugler, and P.~R. ten Wolde.
\newblock Optimal prediction by cellular signaling networks.
\newblock {\em Phys. Rev. Lett.}, 115:258103, 2015.

\end{thebibliography}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know if it fits your needs, but if you don't use the package `babel` and use (uncomment) the syntax `\renewcommand\refname{Supplementary References}`, the `References` will appear with your desired text followed by the section number as you defined in the line starting with `titleformat`.

I would also suggest to inform a MWE, removing all non necessary packages if this idea does not fit your needs.